# In activiti can we assign task to users in round robin fashion depending upon location of user and form location?

Tags: activiti

Can we assign task to users in round robin fashion depending upon location of user and form location?

Comment: please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Activiti is very flexible and task assignment can take many forms.
In order to do this, you would do it one of two ways:
1. Create a service task that populates a list of userid's based on a decision service or external call.
2. Create a Task listener associated with the "assign" event that calls out to a service and then makes the task assignment directly.

Hope this helps,
Greg